# Building blocks for a mobile solution

Tags: architecture, mobile

I am completly new to mobile devlopemtn and I need to work on mobile solution sitting on top of already existing Asp.net portal.

I am interested to know

1 What are the building blocks of a  mobile solution? I can think of few as listed below. Please help me expand my horizon

```
  a. Authentication

  b. UI

  c. Content provider

  d. Protocol

  e. Users
```

2 what are nonfunctional requirement I need to take care of

Thanks

SA

Answer (score 0):

If you are building this on top of an ASP.NET site, then you should know that in ASP.NET you can check if the request is coming from a regular browser or a mobile device browser.

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

Yes, it does not work 100% of the time, but you can play around with that.  This way you don't have to build a mobile solution from scratch, but just do the checking and redirect to a different set of UI pages designed for mobile browsers.